# PHP Access Object included in a class.

Tags: php, mysql

I am using wamp server with php and mysql in windows 7.Have a class that connects to mysql database , a db__connect file is used to establish connection.

Below is the code for the db_connect;

```html
<?php


include_once 'psl-config.php';   // Needed because functions.php is not included
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Unable to connect to MySQL");
    exit();
}
```

Below is the clas code :

```html
<?php

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/datacentre/admin/includes/db_connect.php';

class User {
 
 function getPermission( $email, $perms) {
 
     if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT members.email , groups.permission FROM members 
                                    JOIN groups ON members.group_id = groups.group_id 
            WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();
        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_email, $user_perms);
  print "yes we can ".$user_perms;
  exit();
  
  if($perms & $user_perms)
  {return true;
       exit();}
 
 return false;
     exit();  
}
  
 }


?>
```

Below is the error message 
[image]

Comment: You declare `$mysqli` in the global scope (which is a bad habit, by the way), then try to use it inside an object method. Those are different scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either declare $mysqli inside your User Class, although I am betting you will want to reuse that connection in other classes.  You would be better off passing $mysqli into the User Class

```
    new User($email, $perms, $mysqli);
```

This of course assumes your instantiating the User class globally and not inside another class.